# Generating specific fields from JSON objects

Tags: python, json

I have a rather massive JSON objects and I'm trying to generate a specific JSON using only certain elements from it.

My current code looks like this:

```
 data = get.req("/v2/users")
    data = json.loads(data)
    print (type(data)) # This returns <class 'list'>
    print (data) # Below for what this returns
    all_data = []
    for d in data:
        login_value = d['login']
        if login_value.startswith('fe'):
            continue
        s = get.req("/v2/users/" + str(login_value)) # Sending another request with each 
                                                     # login from the first request
        all_data.append(s)
        print (all_data) # Below for what this looks like this
```

`print (data)` before `json.loads` is `str` for the information, it returns data like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 68663,
        "login": "test1",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 67344,
        "login": "test2",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    },
    {
        "id": 66095,
        "login": "hi",
        "url": "https://x.com/test"
    }
]
```

`print (all_data)` returns a similar result to this for every user a request was sent for the first time

```
[b'{"id":68663,"email":"x@gmail.com","login":"xg","phone":"hidden","fullname":"xg gx","image_url":"https://imgur.com/random.png","mod":false,"points":5,"activity":0,"groups":['skill': 'archery']}
```

And this repeats for every user.

What I'm attempting to do is filtering by a few fields from all those results I received, so the final JSON I have will look something like this

```
[
   {
       "email": "x@gmail.com",
       "fullname": "xg gf",
       "points": 5,
       "image_url", "https://imgur.com/random.pmg"
   },
   {
        ... similar json for the next user and so on
   }
]
```

I feel as if the way I'm iterating over the data might be inefficient, so if you could guide me to a better way it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write:

```
data = get.req("/v2/users")
    data = json.loads(data)
    all_data = []
    for d in data:
        ...
        s = get.req("/v2/users/" + str(login_value))
        new_data = {
            'email': s['email'],
            'fullname': s['fullname'],
            'points': s['points'],
            'image_url': s['image_url']
        }
        all_data.append(new_data)
        print (all_data)
```

or you can make it fancy using an array with the fields you need:

```
data = get.req("/v2/users")
    data = json.loads(data)
    all_data = []
    fields = ['email', 'fullname', 'point', 'image_url']
    for d in data:
        ...
        s = get.req("/v2/users/" + str(login_value))        
        new_data = dict()
        for field in fields:
            new_data[field] = s[field]
        all_data.append(new_data)
        print (all_data)
```

Comment: I tried the second example but I'm getting `byte indices must be integers or slices, not str`, can I know why?

Comment: The response you receive is a byte type -> see end of your post: [b'{"id":68663,"email"...]
You need to convert your bytes to a json object like this:
import json
...
s = get.req("/v2/users/" + str(login_value))
s = json.loads(s)
...

Comment: @HiThere because s is in byte form and you need to convert it into dict for indexing.

Comment: @LetItBeAndre final question if possible, assuming there is a field I want but it exists inside one of the elements like `group[{'skill': 'archery'}]` (see my post) and I want to bring it to the fields as well, how I would go around doing that using the second example? If I simply add it to the array of fields I have it gives `KeyError: 'skill'`

Comment: This is a bit tricky because groups is a list so you can't access elements by a keyword. To retrieve: ```groups[{'skill': 'archery'}]``` you need: ```groups[0]['skill']```
The most straight forward way would possibly be to have a second array
```group_fields = ['skill']```
after iterating through the fields:
```for group_field in group_fields:
    for element in s['groups']:
        if element.get(group_field):
           new_data[group_field] = element.get(group_field)
   all_data.append(new_data)```
Sorry for the code format! The comment field is indeed not too good to post code ;)

Answer (score 2):

In order for you to fetch `login` value, you have to iterate over data atleast once and for fetching details for every user, you have to make one call and that is exactly what you have done.

After you receive the user details instead of appending the whole object to the `all_data` list just take the field you need and construct a dict of it and then append it to `all_data`.

So your code has time complexity of O(n) which is best I understand.

**Edit :**

For each user you are receiving a byte response like below.

```
byte_response = [ b'{"id":68663,"email":"x@gmail.com","login":"xg","phone":"hidden","fullname":"xg gx","image_url":"https://imgur.com/random.png","mod":false,"points":5,"activity":0,"groups":[]}']
```

I'm not sure why would you get a response in a list [],  but if it like that then take byte_response[0] so that we have the actual byte data like below.

```
byte_response = b'{"id":68663,"email":"x@gmail.com","login":"xg","phone":"hidden","fullname":"xg gx","image_url":"https://imgur.com/random.png","mod":false,"points":5,"activity":0,"groups":[]}'

response_decoded = byte_response.decode("utf-8") #decode it

import json
json_object_in_dict_form = json.loads(response_decoded) #convert it into dictionary
```

and then...

```
json_object_in_dict_form['take the field u want']
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to construct the dict based on the example above? That would be very helpful, thanks again.

Comment: @HiThere Edited my answer.